# WPF Unexpected behavior binding ObservableCollection to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a bunch of user controls to a WPF application. The idea is the viewmodel holds the list of server names, passes those to an `ObservableCollection`, and then the collection is bound to the main window.

When in design mode, everything works just fine! However, when I run the application, the binding seems to break down, and I'm at a loss to explain why.

[image]

This is the XAML for the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ServerMonitor.Wpf.ServerControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ServerMonitor.Wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:Server />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="8" Text="{Binding LastPolled}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is the view model (ViewModelBase is an abstract class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged):

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase {

    private List<string> _MachineNames = new List<string> {
        "wschampad",
        // Test
        "T009", "T010", "T011", "T012",
    };
    public List<string> MachineNames {
        get { return _MachineNames; }
        set { _MachineNames = value; OnPropertyChanged("ManchineNames"); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Server> _Servers;
    public ObservableCollection<Server> Servers {
        get {
            if (_Servers == null) {
                _Servers = new ObservableCollection<Server>();
                foreach (var machine in MachineNames) {
                    _Servers.Add(new Server {
                        Name = machine, 
                        LastPolled = DateTime.Now, 
                    });
                }
                OnPropertyChanged("Servers");
            }

            return _Servers;
        }
        set { _Servers = value; OnPropertyChanged("Servers"); }
    }
}
```

And this is the main window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ServerMonitor.Wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ServerMonitor.Wpf"
        Title="Leading Hedge Server Monitor" Height="350" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Menu Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Name="MenuFileExit" Click="MenuFileExit_Click" />

            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit">
                <MenuItem Header="_Options" Name="MenuEditOptions" IsEnabled="False" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help">
                <MenuItem Header="_About" Name="MenuHelpAbout" IsEnabled="False" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Servers}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                        <local:ServerControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT**

Changing the DataContext within the UserControl to ignorable worked to correct the issue!

```
<UserControl x:Class="ServerMonitor.Wpf.ServerControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ServerMonitor.Wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <d:UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:Server />
    </d:UserControl.DataContext>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of this in your UserControl:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:Server />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

This is overwriting your `DataContext` you're passing to it from the `ItemTemplate`, and you end up with default values for `DateTime` and `string`.

Comment: That worked! However, I tweaked this slightly, so that I could preserve the intellisense.      <d:UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:Server />
    </d:UserControl.DataContext>

Comment: Yep, I was going to add that if you said you wanted the IntelliSense help still :)

Comment: Thanks for the help with this. It never occured to me that the control's binding would take precedence.

Comment: And Love Live Netscape!